# Netezza system catalog table constains duplicate records for external tables

Tags: netezza, catalog

In my Netezza box, I can see duplicate records in system tables. It is specific to EXTERNAL TABLE records as shown below

Example:

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE “Joe” (“Id” integer)

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)-> USING (DATAOBJECT(‘filename.csv’)

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)(> REMOTESOURCE ‘odbc’);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select tablename, objtype from _v_table where tablename =’Joe’;
TABLENAME | OBJTYPE

———–+—————-

Joe | EXTERNAL TABLE

Joe | EXTERNAL TABLE

(2 rows)

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select tablename, objtype from _v_table where objtype =’EXTERNAL TABLE’;

TABLENAME | OBJTYPE

———————————————————-+—————-
STG_TBLMEMBERS_HIST_EXT_ef8de7e9c2b14692bf61848d5fd20858 | EXTERNAL TABLE
STG_TBLMEMBERS_HIST_EXT_ef8de7e9c2b14692bf61848d5fd20858 | EXTERNAL TABLE

Joe | EXTERNAL TABLE`

Joe | EXTERNAL TABLE

(4 rows)
```

Even OBJECTID is also same for these 2 duplicate records. I could not found the reason for it. Please help and let me know what could be the reason for it.

Thanks

Comment: This is likely a bug in a system view for your release, which I can reproduce in some releases but not others. I would recommend pursuing this with support.

Answer (score 0):

This has been confirmed as a bug, and fixed in subsequent patches/releases.