# Netezza: While creating external table, column name is duped with same data type, need to know the reason

Tags: netezza

I am creating external table in netezza. After table creation when I am describing it, I can see all column are duped 4 times. It looks strange to me but its happening.

Example:

```
    CREATE external TABLE TEST '/nzscratch/kapish/69314.082.000/TV_Daily_Audit_Results.txt'
            USING(delim '|' Format 'TEXT'
           ) AS
    SELECT
        b.card_acceptor_id AS MID,
        a.div_no AS CARD_DIV_NO,
        c.div_name AS ACCT_TYPE,
        a.acct_id,
        a.tran_text,
        substr(a.tran_text, 24, 13) AS MERCHANT_CITY,
        substr(a.tran_text, 37, 2) AS MERCHANT_STATE,
        b.MERCHANT_ZIP_CD,
        a.post_date,
        a.tran_cd,
        a.gl_origin_cd,
        a.tran_amt,
        a.merchant_cat_cd
    FROM
        pstdtr_pstd_trans a,
        pstdrt_rtain_rtns b,
        divdef_div_def_v c
    WHERE
        a.acct_id = b.acct_id
        AND a.reference_no = b.reference_no
        AND a.tran_date = b.tran_date
        AND a.div_no = c.div_no
        AND a.div_no IN (232, 234, 235, 237, 273, 275, 276, 278)
        AND post_date >= (current_date - 2)
        AND gl_origin_cd NOT IN (232, 234, 235, 237, 273, 275, 276, 278)

    SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \d TEST

      External Table "TV_DAILY_AUDIT_RESULTS"
    Attribute    |         Type          | Modifier
-----------------+-----------------------+----------

MID             | CHARACTER(15)         |

MID             | CHARACTER(15)         |

MID             | CHARACTER(15)         |

MID             | CHARACTER(15)         |

CARD_DIV_NO     | SMALLINT              | NOT NULL

CARD_DIV_NO     | SMALLINT              | NOT NULL

CARD_DIV_NO     | SMALLINT              | NOT NULL

CARD_DIV_NO     | SMALLINT              | NOT NULL

ACCT_TYPE       | CHARACTER(30)         |

..

..

..

MERCHANT_CAT_CD | INTEGER               |

MERCHANT_CAT_CD | INTEGER               |

MERCHANT_CAT_CD | INTEGER               |

MERCHANT_CAT_CD | INTEGER               |

DataObject - 'C:\WinSQL Jobs\Daily TV Audit\TV_Daily_Audit_Results.txt'

DataObject - 'C:\WinSQL Jobs\Daily TV Audit\TV_Daily_Audit_Results.txt'

DataObject - 'C:\WinSQL Jobs\Daily TV Audit\TV_Daily_Audit_Results.txt'

DataObject - 'C:\WinSQL Jobs\Daily TV Audit\TV_Daily_Audit_Results.txt'

adjustdistzeroint   -

bool style          - 1_0
.

.

decimaldelim        -

disablenfc          -

includeheader       -
```

Now sure what is the reason for it. So if any one can help me, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the same bug/issue recognized in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602818/netezza-system-catalog-table-constains-duplicate-records-for-external-tables), which has been resolved by subsequent fixes/releases.  You should contact support for the fix.

The table should function as normal, despite the odd report from the catalog.